# Call Method from MainActivity after completely loading RecyclerView Cards inside a Fragment inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

My MainActivity contains a ViewPager that I attached to a FragmentPagerAdapter which loads Fragments.  Now those Fragments themselves consist of RecyclerView Cards list.  That is inturn attached to a RecyclerView Adapter.

I am trying to call a method from MainActivity on startup that accesses a particular TextView inside the Card which is part of the RecyclerView which is part of the Fragment which is part of the ViewPager.

I try to create a public object inside the ViewPager Adapter and point it to my TextView in onBindViewHolder and later on access this object from the MainActivity but I get null.  I have learned that onBindViewHolder is called way before the contents are actually rendered on the activity and thus my object is null on startup.

So how/when shall I call my method so that all the objects are safely loaded and I can access the objects safely.

**Some Code**

I am using this code in onCreateView of my Fragment class to access some objects in the fragment.  This works well.

```
 //set anchor points
        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).mAnchor1 = mainTitle;
        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).mAnchor2 = dlcButton;
        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).mAnchor3 = scanButton;

    return  vindexFragment;
```

Comment: can you describe why do you need it, and what should it do, because it is hard to understand the functionality from the description.

Comment: thersa library called TourGuide used for introducing interface to the users by displaying tool tips next to Views in the Activity.  For that, the API wants all the objects(for which tooltip is needed) to be passed to it.  I am trying to pass some objects which is inside the RecyclerView (inside Fragment inside ViewPager).  I do this by declaring some public objects in the activity and then setting them to the RecyclerView cards item in the onBindView() method of the recyclerview.  Then I pass these objects in activity to the TourGuide.  Unfortunately, my objects are all null so far...

Comment: why can't you use it in the Fragment using onitemclicklistener at ListView, and getting the clicked View and Object from there?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to make a item listener in RecyclerView?

Comment: The TourGuide library needs an array of objects.  It displays tooltips with a dark transparent overlay and highlights the corresponding object.  It is automated.  When the user taps the overlay, it moves to the next object and displays its corresponding tooltip.  Its a quick intro and the user is supposed just watch, tap, watch, tap and so on until its over.  The user can't click on the recyclerView or interact with any other object.

I only want to access an object inside recyclerView from the activity on **startup**.  Thats all.

Comment: Ok I understand the problem. Why can't you call -
TourGuide.init(getContext()).with(TourGuide.Technique.Click)
            .setPointer(new Pointer())
            .setToolTip(new ToolTip().setTitle("Welcome!").setDescription("Click on Get Started to begin..."))
            .setOverlay(new Overlay())
            .playOn(holder.yourView); in onBindViewHolder, the View shouldn't be null.

Comment: Yea, worked! I used a different method (of sequence in the TourGuide API) but I still triggered it from the place you suggested - in onBindViewHolder.  Quite simple... thanks!